# SonarQube starts and then stops

Tags: sonarqube

I am trying to start the sonarqube with `./sonar.sh start` command. It starts for 5 secs and then stops on it own.

The log file shows this:

```
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:811) [na:2.9 (11-22-2017)]
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
        at org.sonar.core.persistence.DefaultDatabase.checkConnection(DefaultDatabase.java:113) ~[sonar-core-4.5.4.jar:na]
        ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:207) ~[postgresql-9.3-1101-jdbc4.jar:na]
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:64) ~[postgresql-9.3-1101-jdbc4.jar:na]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:138) ~[postgresql-9.3-1101-jdbc4.jar:na]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:29) ~[postgresql-9.3-1101-jdbc4.jar:na]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:21) ~[postgresql-9.3-1101-jdbc4.jar:na]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:31) ~[postgresql-9.3-1101-jdbc4.jar:na]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:24) ~[postgresql-9.3-1101-jdbc4.jar:na]
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:410) ~[postgresql-9.3-1101-jdbc4.jar:na]
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:280) ~[postgresql-9.3-1101-jdbc4.jar:na]
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
        ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:380) ~[na:1.8.0]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:236) ~[na:1.8.0]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:218) ~[na:1.8.0]
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403) ~[na:1.8.0]
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:666) ~[na:1.8.0]
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:606) ~[na:1.8.0]
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:60) ~[postgresql-9.3-1101-jdbc4.jar:na]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:101) ~[postgresql-9.3-1101-jdbc4.jar:na]
        ... 42 common frames omitted
2018.04.16 03:16:44 INFO  web[jruby.rack]  jruby 1.7.9 (ruby-1.8.7p370) 2013-12-06 87b108a on IBM J9 VM 8.0.5.6 - pxa6480sr5fp6-20171124_02(SR5 FP6) [linux-amd64]
2018.04.16 03:16:44 INFO  web[jruby.rack]  using a shared (threadsafe!) runtime
2018.04.16 03:16:51 ERROR web[jruby.rack]  initialization failed
org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException.wrap(RackInitializationException.java:31) ~[jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.rack.DefaultRackApplicationFactory.getApplication(DefaultRackApplicationFactory.java:111) ~[jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.rack.SharedRackApplicationFactory.doInit(SharedRackApplicationFactory.java:31) ~[jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.rack.RackApplicationFactoryDecorator.init(RackApplicationFactoryDecorator.java:94) ~[jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar:na]
        ... 10 common frames omitted
2018.04.16 03:16:51 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.StandardContext]  Error listenerStart
2018.04.16 03:16:51 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.StandardContext]  Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
2018.04.16 03:16:51 ERROR web[o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoader]  The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [JRubyJIT-2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2018.04.16 03:16:51 ERROR web[o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoader]  The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [JRubyJIT-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2018.04.16 03:16:51 ERROR web[o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoader]  The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [Timer-0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2018.04.16 03:16:51 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11Protocol]  Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2018.04.16 03:16:51 INFO  web[o.s.s.app.Logging]  Web server is started
2018.04.16 03:16:51 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.EmbeddedTomcat]  HTTP connector enabled on port 9000
2018.04.16 03:16:51 WARN  web[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint]  Fail to start web
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Webapp did not start
        at org.sonar.server.app.EmbeddedTomcat.isReady(EmbeddedTomcat.java:83) ~[sonar-server-4.5.4.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.isReady(WebServer.java:45) [sonar-server-4.5.4.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:80) ~[sonar-process-4.5.4.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.main(WebServer.java:65) [sonar-server-4.5.4.jar:na]
2018.04.16 03:16:51 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11Protocol]  Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2018.04.16 03:16:52 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11Protocol]  Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2018.04.16 03:16:52 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11Protocol]  Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2018.04.16 03:16:52 INFO  web[o.s.s.app.Logging]  Web server is stopped
2018.04.16 03:16:52 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.TerminatorThread] Process[search] is stopping
2018.04.16 03:16:52 INFO  sea[o.s.p.StopWatcher]  Stopping process
2018.04.16 03:16:52 INFO  sea[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1523828793595] stopping ...
2018.04.16 03:16:52 INFO  sea[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1523828793595] stopped
2018.04.16 03:16:52 INFO  sea[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1523828793595] closing ...
2018.04.16 03:16:52 INFO  sea[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1523828793595] closed
2018.04.16 03:16:52 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.TerminatorThread] Process[search] is stopped
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Could you please help me out in here?

Sonar.properties

```
sonar.jdbc.maxActive=20
sonar.jdbc.maxIdle=5
sonar.jdbc.minIdle=2
sonar.jdbc.maxWait=5000
sonar.jdbc.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=600000
sonar.jdbc.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=30000
```

wrapper.properties

```
wrapper.java.command=java
wrapper.java.additional.1=-Djava.awt.headless=true
wrapper.java.mainclass=org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp
wrapper.java.classpath.1=../../lib/jsw/*.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.2=../../lib/*.jar
wrapper.java.library.path.1=./lib
wrapper.app.parameter.1=org.sonar.application.App
wrapper.java.initmemory=3
# Xmx can't be set to a lower value because of compatibility with Java 6
wrapper.java.maxmemory=32
```

Also, no other process is running on port 9000 which is being given to sonarqube

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SonarQube is configured to use a Postgresql database, however your server is not able to connect to this database, according to this error :

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

You should check the `sonar.jdbc.url` property.

Answer (score 0):

Did you uncomment these lines in sonar.properties?(sonarqube_folder/conf/sonar.properties)

```
 sonar.jdbc.username= 
 sonar.jdbc.password=
 sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sonar
```

And set the username, password to the ones you have set for the role?
For example:

```
 sonar.jdbc.username=sonar 
 sonar.jdbc.password=sonar
```

I faced another problem before i didn't set role's permissions when i created a role and after rebooting my pc i couldn't connect to database. After creating a new role i had to Right click on new role and add permissions in pgAdmin. Sometimes i also had to manually connect to server.

- Open pgAdmin
- Right click on server and connect